# How to randomly allocate values to a field from a set?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two columns in my table profile which are `id` and `education`. Now I want to randomly allocate education field values which can be in this set`('HA','BA,'CA' and 'DA')`. How can I do this in one command. `id` is a primary key for this table.

Comment: You want to populate your table with random 'education' values?

Comment: yup but these should be from this set only which is mentioned in question.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with a sql-command. But you could create a very simple php script to populate the table with this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [`ELT(N,str1,str2,str3,…)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_elt):

> Returns `str1` if `N = 1`, `str2` if `N = 2`, and so on.

As documented under [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> To obtain a random integer *`R`* in the range *`i <= R < j`*, use the expression `FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i))`.

Therefore:

```
UPDATE my_table SET education = ELT(FLOOR(1 + RAND() * 4), 'HA', 'BA', 'CA', 'DA')
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39b12/1/0).